# Unable to install postgis extenstion with greenplum

Tags: unix, postgis, devops, greenplum

I have installed greenplum4.3.1.9 on rhel7 server, but i am not able to install postgis extension with greenplum. please help.

While i am installing postgis extension using gppkg package, i am getting following error:

```
-bash-4.2$ gppkg -i postgis-ossv2.0.3_pv2.0.1_gpdb4.3orca-rhel5-x86_64.gppkg
20180116:16:15:14:011874 gppkg:Mongo1:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Starting gppkg with args: -i postgis-ossv2.0.3_pv2.0.1_gpdb4.3orca-rhel5-x86_64.gppkg
20180116:16:15:15:011874 gppkg:Mongo1:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Installing package postgis-ossv2.0.3_pv2.0.1_gpdb4.3orca-rhel5-x86_64.gppkg
20180116:16:15:15:011874 gppkg:Mongo1:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Validating rpm installation cmdStr='rpm --test -i /data/greenplum/.tmp/postgis-2.0.3-2.x86_64.rpm /data/greenplum/.tmp/geos-3.3.8-1.x86_64.rpm /data/greenplum/.tmp/proj-4.8.0-1.x86_64.rpm --dbpath /data/greenplum/share/packages/database --prefix /data/greenplum'
20180116:16:15:16:011874 gppkg:Mongo1:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Installing postgis-ossv2.0.3_pv2.0.1_gpdb4.3orca-rhel5-x86_64.gppkg locally
20180116:16:15:16:011874 gppkg:Mongo1:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Validating rpm installation cmdStr='rpm --test -i /data/greenplum/.tmp/postgis-2.0.3-2.x86_64.rpm /data/greenplum/.tmp/geos-3.3.8-1.x86_64.rpm /data/greenplum/.tmp/proj-4.8.0-1.x86_64.rpm --dbpath /data/greenplum/share/packages/database --prefix /data/greenplum'
20180116:16:15:16:011874 gppkg:Mongo1:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Installing rpms cmdStr='rpm -i /data/greenplum/.tmp/postgis-2.0.3-2.x86_64.rpm /data/greenplum/.tmp/geos-3.3.8-1.x86_64.rpm /data/greenplum/.tmp/proj-4.8.0-1.x86_64.rpm --dbpath /data/greenplum/share/packages/database --prefix=/data/greenplum'
20180116:16:15:17:011874 gppkg:Mongo1:gpadmin-[CRITICAL]:-Error occurred: non-zero rc: 3
 Command was: 'rpm -i /data/greenplum/.tmp/postgis-2.0.3-2.x86_64.rpm /data/greenplum/.tmp/geos-3.3.8-1.x86_64.rpm /data/greenplum/.tmp/proj-4.8.0-1.x86_64.rpm --dbpath /data/greenplum/share/packages/database --prefix=/data/greenplum'
rc=3, stdout='', stderr='error: unpacking of archive failed on file /data/greenplum/lib/libproj.a;5a5dd7bd: cpio: open
error: proj-4.8.0-1.x86_64: install failed
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /data/greenplum/lib/libgeos-3.3.8.so;5a5dd7bd: cpio: open
error: geos-3.3.8-1.x86_64: install failed
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /data/greenplum/bin/pgsql2shp;5a5dd7bd: cpio: open
error: postgis-2.0.3-2.x86_64: install failed
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Did you download the package from network.pivotal.io and use gppkg to install it?

Comment: @ Jon Roberts, Yes, i have downloaded the gppkg package from pivotal and when tried to install using gppkg, i am getting the errors (updated in the question description)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is redownloading the package and installing, it could be that the package itself was corrupted. It looks like it was attempting to pull files out of the internal rpm package and failed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with [Scott Kahler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7291588/scott-kahler), Try to download new package againg or run gppkg in -verbose mode to get more details on error. The issue might be you don't have unarchiver utility installed that gppkg is using.